# Cannot Translate to SQL using Select(x => Func(x))

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm slowly learning the ins and outs of LINQtoSQL, but this is confusing me.

Here is the statement I have:

```
IQueryable<IEvent> events = (from e in db.getEvents()
                            select e).Select(x => SelectEvent(x, null));
```

What the SelectEvent does can be explained in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319847/return-different-objects-with-one-linqtosql-statement/2320010#2320010).  I am not using the .toList() function as I don't want potentially thousands of records brought into memory.

```
public IEvent SelectEvent(SqlServer.Event ev, EventType? type) {
    // Create an object which implements IEvent
    // I don't have the code in front of me, so forgive the lack of code
}
```

My question is really for the `Select()` method.  I get the "Cannot translate to SQL" error and the `Select()` is listed in the error message.

Clueless on this one :-/.

Comment: This is the difference between lambdas as delegates and lambdas as expression trees. In short, you can't do it that way. Can you show what `SelectEvent` is trying to do please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq to SQL cannot translate arbitrary function calls like that to SQL. It has no idea what the function does. You'll have to construct whatever SelectEvent does using expressions.

Alternatively, if all you want to do is map the objects to something else after the query has gone through the database, just do it as you're looping through the results, or create a wrapping generator that does it for you.

Comment: All great answers - marking yours as the answer as you're first :P.  Makes a lot of sense.  The main reason for the SelectEvent method was due to it having a `switch` statement - I create a specific event of type IEvent.  I'm not sure how to do that with just a linq2sql expression.

Answer (score 3):

It's complaining (reasonably) that it can't turn the call to `SelectEvent` into SQL.

If you put `.AsEnumerable()` before the `.Select()` C# will use the IEnumerable Select over the IQueryable Select:

```
interface IEnumerable<T> {
    ...
    // Actually, these are extension methods in Enumerable and Queryable.
    IEnumerable<T> Select<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> selector);
    ...
}

interface IQueryable<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    ...
    IQueryable<T> Select<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> selector);
    ...
    IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable();
}

IEnumerable<IEvent> events = db.getEvents().AsEnumerable().Select(x => SelectEvent(x, null));
```

Or, if you could use a `IEvent SelectEvent(SqlServer.Event)` overload immediately, since it is not convertible to an Expression<>:

```
IEnumerable<IEvent> events = db.getEvents().Select(SelectEvent);
```

The IEnumerable Select executes the `Func<T, TResult>` selector once for each item returned from the source IEnumerable, the IQueryable Select passes the `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>` selector to the LINQ provider - which in the case of LINQ2SQL tries to generate the equivalent SQL.

Comment: How would this work with paging?  My concern is that if I get all the events into memory, isn't that worse than just getting a page of data from the SQL server?  Thanks for the answer +1

Comment: "run it locally" was referring only to the execution of SelectEvent, the data is still retrieved the same way. Edited.

Comment: @SimonBuchan I'm running into a similar issue and I'm looking for a workaround. Could you elaborate more on the IEvent SelectEvent(SqlServer.Event)? I googled a bit, but I'm not sure I understand this. I would take in an event, and then....I would apply an argument to that event and return what? Also, this doesn't get translated to an expression tree, but would run locally, right - so can this be succeeded by LINQ-to-SQL expression methods, like .Take() and .Where()? Or would that spit out an IEnumerable in memory? Sorry for the barrage of questions, I'm out of my depth but want to understand!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that in LinqToSQL your query is first translated to an expression tree and then later into actual running SQL code.  There is only a small subset of C# code in expression tree form which can be converted to SQL.

In this case the expression tree is including a call to a method which resides in the current assembly (`SelectEvent`).  There is no way for the convert to translate this method into code that can run in the SQL server so it throws an error.

To work around this try inlining the code for `SelectEvent` into the query expression.

Comment: Seems that functions inside a LINQtoSQL expression are generally a bad idea.  Makes sense, but I wish it wasn't so :P.  Thanks! +1